# "databricks -o json" inconsistent output between empty array and "null"

Tags: shell, databricks

Trying to understand some weird behavior in Bash.

I'm querying an API (the databricks api) using their CLI-wrapper, so the API request gets sent via a CLI-formatted command. I'm using Bash to send these CLI command.

The "-o json" in my command requests to get the response in JSON format. Most of the time you'll get a regular JSON, as if you queried the API directly. However sometimes you'll get an empty response, which the CLI returns as a string literal of "null".

The exact command is `databricks jobs list --name MyJobName -o json`. When I run it on my Mac (pointing at the same API and same Job Name, I get a result of "null", like this:

```
(base) % JOB_IF_EXISTS=$(databricks jobs list --name "$JOB_NAME" -o json)
(base) % echo "$JOB_IF_EXISTS"
null
```

However when I run it in Bash, I get an empty array, formatted with whitespace. This means I have to parse it as an array instead of string, and I can't use the standard "-z" for checking if it's empty.

This is what my bash code looks like:

```
# Check if the job exists
echo "Finding job if exists..."
JOB_IF_EXISTS=$(databricks jobs list --name "$JOB_NAME" -o json)
echo "JOB_IF_EXISTS: $JOB_IF_EXISTS"
```

And this is what gets printed in my logs:

```
Finding job if exists...
JOB_IF_EXISTS: [
  
]
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Is my string literal "null" getting parsed out into an array? Why is that happening?

Comment: Your question focus to much on `databrick`, you should provide a sample input that we can use with `echo` or `cat` to test. And   
do read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you getting these different results on the same computer or different ones? (I'm wondering if you're using different versions of whatever `databricks` is and the behavior changed at some point in a newer release)

Comment: OMG @Shawn you're right! This was the issue! I just upgraded my local Databrick CLI version and now I get the same result as I did in bash. Bash was running separately from my computer. Thank you so much!! Feel free to post it as the answer and I'd be happy to upvote and check it

Comment: It's bad practice to return `null` when you mean `empty list`. Maybe the Databricks developers realized and fixed the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the `null` output was coming from an old outdated version of `databricks`. Updating it makes running the command return an empty array in both environments.

In cases like this, it's always a good idea to figure out what's *different* between the setups - I'm assuming the shell being used on the Mac is `zsh` instead of `bash`, but that shouldn't make a difference in this case, so the obvious next thing to check is the version of the tool producing the differing output.

---

As a followup, to check to see if a JSON array is empty in shell, I'd turn to `jq`:

```bash
# For bash and zsh, not sh
if [[ "$(jq length <<<"$JOB_IF_EXISTS")" -eq 0 ]]; then
  # do something if non-empty
else
  # do something if empty
fi
```